# Integrating RFT and RQM with and Excel datapool

Tags: excel, rft

I am trying to integrate RFT with RQM. All of our scripts are data dependent,the data being pulled from an Excel Datapool at run-time. But when I try to playback a script through RQM, the data pool values are not taken in. So I would like to know, whether RQM has got any difficulties in accepting data from an excel datapool and If yes, what should I do in order to pull out data from datapool and thereby make the playback work smoothly.